# can I revert awarding a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

On [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568228/controlling-bluetooth-mouse-gestures-that-register-keyboard-events) I had a bounty going for a few more days but was so excited that I had got an answer that appeared to work, I assigned it. However, later I noticed it wasn't working right and realized I didn't properly test it. It didn't solve the problem for me. That being said, is there any way to revert the bounty? Not like I don't think the user was helpful, but the whole point in having the bounty was to potentially get the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Awarding a bounty is permanent and cannot be undone. When you award a bounty, the following message is displayed:

[image]

Comment: it wasn't an immediate response and so i had forgotten, which is why i asked. thanks for the reminder.